# SQL update statement with replace or trim

Tags: sql, replace

I have a table with a column that contains data like this

```
Column X
Sprint 1, Sprint 2, Sprint 3
Sprint 1
Sprint 2, Sprint 3
Sprint 4
Sprint 3, Sprint 4
```

What I want to do is update the data in the column and keep only the text after the last comma, so the final result would be:

```
Column X
Sprint 3
Sprint 1
Sprint 3
Sprint 4
Sprint 4
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, explain why you are storing multiple values in a single column.  The correct approach is to use another table for a list.

Comment: Comma separated values in a column is a mess. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Is regular expression replacement available on your database? That would be the easiest and most readable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL this will work.

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(X, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(',' + X)) - 1))
FROM TableName
```

Not sure about other databases

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do the update:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
  SELECT COLUMN_X,         
         LTRIM(RIGHT(COLUMN_X, IIF(t.i = 0, LEN(COLUMN_X), t.i - 1))) AS new_X
  FROM mytable 
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(COLUMN_X)))) AS t(i)
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Column_X = new_X
```

**Note:** The above works in SQL Server 2012+.

The following works in MySQL:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET COLUMN_X = LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_X, ',', -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> UPDATE table1 SET columnx = SUBSTRING(columnx,LENGTH(columnx)-8,LENGTH(columnx)+1);
```

I have tried with the above query on postgresSQL and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

the following should work as well:

```
SELECT MID(column,len(column)-7,8) AS new_value
FROM table_name;
```

(this works if the number after 'sprint' is a single digit)